# npx not creating public and src folders in react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

when executed the command to create the env for react
npx create-react-app myfirstapp,
command was successfull but there were few warnings.
Src and public folders not created.
OS Windows 10 home edition.

[image]

Comment: can you do 'dir' in you project?

Comment: Most likely a problem with your network connection, try deleting the generated react app, and run `npx create-react-app myfirstapp` again

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues, I solved it by executing:

- `npm install -g create-react-app`
- `create-react-app >>app-name<<`